# gCentroid shifting centroid towards concentration of points

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a [SpatialPointsDataFrame](https://pastebin.com/PPVirRQ4) defining SD boundary, however when I compute the center with `gCentroid` it's shifted.

```
c. = rgeos::gCentroid(c.) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Why isn't it plotting it at the center?
[image]

Comment: if you apply gCentroid to the bounding box does it still plot like that?

Comment: good idea, let me try

Comment: however, the draw back of finding the centroid of the bounding box is that it won't be very well placed for 'strangely' shaped polygons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the mass of points is higher in the lower right corner. If you transform your object to a `SpatialPolygons` object (making it *one* shape) then it works:

```
poly <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons( srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordinates(dat))), ID = 1)))
gCentroid(spgeom = poly)

plot(poly)
axis(1)
axis(2)
points(gCentroid(poly))
```

[image]