# Find visual center of a polygon

Tags: r, polygon, distance, centroid

Follow up from this question: [gCentroid shifting centroid towards concentration of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736565/gcentroid-shifting-centroid-towards-concentration-of-points), but with a trickier shape.

Using this [SpatialPointsDataFrame](https://pastebin.com/MY1uWNUc) I calculated the center using `gCentroid`, but it places it outside the shape.

```
# c. = [dput'd data from link]
poly <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons( srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordinates(c.))), ID = 1)))
plot(poly)
axis(1)
axis(2)
points(rgeos::gCentroid(poly))
```

[image]

How can I return coordinates for a center point that falls *inside* the specified shape?

As pointed out in the comments for these sort of shapes, the center falls outside the boundaries. What I am looking for I think is better described as the "center of mass", the point *within* a polygon that is farthest from boundaries.

[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I was in school but I believe that only convex polygons are guaranteed to have a centroid inside the shape.

Comment: Think of a torus (a region with two concentric rings as the boundary).  OF COURSE the centroid is outside the region.  If you want something inside the region,  you will have to define what you are looking for.

Comment: A very closely related question about finding the "visual center" of an irregular polygon has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203135/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-visual-center-of-an-irregularly-shaped-pol/65409262#65409262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`polylabelR::poi`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/polylabelr/html/poi.html) (Pole of Inaccessibility (Visual Center) of a Polygon) seems to do the trick. Related approach: https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc

```
poly <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons( srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordinates(c.))), ID = 1)))
plot(poly)
axis(1)
axis(2)
points(rgeos::gCentroid(c.)) 

p <- polylabelr::poi(xx$long, xx$lat, precision = 0.01)
points(p)
```

[image]